# (js)regular expression for matching a words only

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a dictionary application and need an  regexp that check if the users input is only letters and spaces eventually. This is probably the most easiest regexp but i can figure it out. So far i have

```
/^[\w\D]$/
```

which is not working :/

---

sorry guys, forgot to mention that will need to exclude all spec characters also.

Comment: Do you just want to exclude digits ? Do you accept other characters ?

Comment: @dystroy, you're right, I'll need to exclude all spec characters also.

Comment: Are you just looking for English chars (then it's easy) or for a solution that wouldn't break with French, German, Chinese, and so on (then it's hard, I'm not even sure my answer is complete).

Comment: @Alordiel Are accented characters considered "special characters", by your definition?

Comment: @dystroy, at this point this will work but once again you are correct. I will need some solution for Spanish and Cyrillic. But i will post another question when i get to this point. thanks a lot.

Comment: My answer should work for Spanish and Cyrillic.

Comment: @Asad, yes. As now I'm working only on words chars as "¿ or ¡" shouldn't be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want this one :

```
/^[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFa-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

It should accept only characters (including "not English" characters like the ones you have in Spanish and Cyrillic) as well as spaces, but exclude digits.

Example :

```
/^[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FFa-zA-Z\s]+$/.test("переполнения стека")
```

returns `true`

Comment: @eidsonator Yes, hence the question I asked in comments, as OP's question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression matches **exactly one** such character.

You can add the `+` modifier to match **one or more** characters.

Comment: \w includes digits, and \D is everything that isn't a digit, so more changes are needed than just adding the quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

To match a string consisting only of letters and whitespace characters, you can use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

Comment: This is a very restrictive interpretation of "letter". Example : "écureil".

Comment: @dystroy Alas, `\w` is just `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Yours works though.

Comment: `/^((?!\d)[\w\s])+$/.test("é")` returns false.